# Authenticating a Xamarin Android app using Azure Active Directory fails with 401 Unauthorzed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I am trying to Authenticate a Xamarin Android app using Azure Active Directory by following article here:
https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-xamarin-mobile-apps-using-azure-active-directory/

1. I have registered a native application with AAD; note that i havent given it any additional permissions beyond creating it.
2. Then i use the below code to authenticate the APP with AAD

```html
button.Click += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(commonAuthority);
                if (authContext.TokenCache.Count > 0)
                    authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().GetEnumerator().Current.Authority);
                authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri, new PlatformParameters(this));

                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


                doGET("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/OPSLABRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/LABVM?api-version=2015-08-01", authResult.AccessToken);

            };
```

```html
private string doGET(string URI, String token)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(URI));

            // Create the request
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

            // Get the response
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
            try
            {
                httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Error from : " + uri + ": " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show(); 
                return null;
            }

        }
```

This seems to be getting a token when using a Work account.
Using a valid hotmail account throws error A Bad Request was received.

However the main problem is when i try to retrieve VM details using REST.
the REST GET method fails with 401 Unauthorized error even when using the Work account.

I am not sure if the code is lacking something or if i need to give some additional permissions for the App. This needs to be able to support authenticating users from other tenants to get VM details.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note that i havent given it any additional permissions beyond creating
> it.

This is the problem here.

In order for you to call the Azure Management API `https://management.azure.com/`, you must first register your application to have permissions to call this API.

You can do that as a part of your app registration like so:
[image]

Only at that point, will your app be authorized to call ARM, and your calls should start to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried this but it is still giving me the same error :(

Comment: What is the sub-message along with the 401?

Comment: This is the entire message: Error from: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/OPSLABRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/LABVM?api-version=2015-08-01: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Comment: Is my problem here:
const string graphResourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net";

authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri, new PlatformParameters(this));

While i am passing the graphResourceUri  above to acquire token, based on the original sample I am working off, it looks incorrect as actually I am trying to call Azure management REST APIs , so maybe i should pass "https://management.azure.com/" or "https://management.core.windows.net/"  as the resource instead??

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: Thank You very much, Finally i got it to work. It works well with organizational accounts. Sadly when using hotmail IDs, it throws error 'Bad Request'. If you have any suggestions, let me know. But I'm a happy man today :)

Comment: I don't think you can make it work for hotmail accounts today. In the near future, our [V2 app model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview) will come to support these things, but it does not yet support ARM as a resource.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side. As Shawn Tabrizi mentioned that you need to assign the delegated permission for accessing ARM Rest API. Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
    "https://management.azure.com/"
    , clientId, new Uri("{redirectUrl}"), platformParameter);
```

I would recommend you using Fiddler or Postman to simulate the request against ARM with the `access_token` to narrow this issue. If any errors, you could check the detailed response for troubleshooting the cause.

Here is my test for retrieving the basic information of my Azure VM:

[image]

Additionally, you could leverage [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) for decoding your `access_token` and check the related properties (e.g. `aud`, `iss`, etc.) as follows to narrow this issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much, Finally i got it to work. It works well with organizational accounts. when using hotmail IDs, it throws error 'Bad Request'. If you have any suggestions, let me know.